# Numeric file name, upload multiple txt files, Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have around 70 .txt files all saved as

```
1.txt, 2.txt
```

and so on. I would like to create a dataframe with just one columne like `fileContent` and in each row have text from each txt file. Each time I try to upload file with the name from array of numbers I get error.
Is it achievable?
It is important that my array is **`[1,2,3,........70]`** not `[1.txt, 2.txt.....70.txt]`

Comment: `pd.series(dict(zip([file for file in os.listdir('path_of_txt_files')],[open(filename, 'r').read() for filename in os.listdir('path_of_txt_files')])))`

Comment: and `pd` is what here?

Comment: import pandas as pd

Comment: i get error AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'series'

Comment: i think it must be camelcase - Series. And what is **os** here ?

Comment: just wrote a complete answer. Hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201780/discussion-between-fzn-and-heisenberg7584).

Comment: ok, wrote there about the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import os

txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir('path_of_txt_files') if '.txt' in f] 
pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dict(zip(txt_files,[open(f,'r').read() for f in txt_files]))))
```

This will create a table containing filenames in one column, and their respective contents in the other column.

Comment: got error:  pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(dict(zip(txt_files,[open(f,'w').read() for f in txt_files]))))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: Sorry my bad. Please use `[open(f,'r').read()` instead of `[open(f,'w').read()`

Comment: all looks good now but now the error appears: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '15.txt'... But there is 15.txt file as well as all others :(